# has_many and has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have Country, City, Shop models

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :shops 
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
end
```

How can I get country.shops in activerecord? (get all shops in country)

I usually use Country.cities.collect { |c| c.shops }
but this is not activerecord object.

I have considered add country_id on shop model and set has_many relation but I think it's not best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Country, add a has_many :through relation:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
  has_many :shops, through: :cities
end
```

Now you can write `country.shops` and receive an appropriate ActiveRecord relation where you can say stuff like `country.shops.where name:"Nieman Marcus"` and other such queries.

Answer (score 0):

you can def a method in Class Country

```
def all_shops
  self.cities.collect { |c| c.shops }
end
```

you alse can use Mongoid::Tree

```
def all_shops
  Shop.where(:parent_ids => self.id)
end
```